# Why does one of these work and the other not?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, multiprocessing

I want to share (and change) a `mutable Vec` across threads, in a scoped thread pool context, using [scoped_thread_pool](https://docs.rs/scoped-thread-pool/latest/scoped_thread_pool/).

```
let ids_for_discard: Arc<Mutex<Vec<String>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));

let scoped_outcome = self.threadpool.scoped(|scope| {
    // here I iterate through a Vec of objects...
    for text_doc_hit_obj in &self.handling_framework.text_doc_hit_objs_for_processing {
        // each thread will need its Arc clone...
        let ids_for_discard = Arc::clone(&ids_for_discard);
        scope.execute(move ||  {
            // this (above) closure MUST return "()"... so
            // I use an inner closure to capture errors efficiently, using the "?" operator several times
            let inner_closure = move || -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
                ...
                let id_string = text_doc_hit_obj._id.clone();
                // let _ = ids_for_discard.lock()?.push(id_string); // fails to compile
                let _ = ids_for_discard.lock().unwrap().push(id_string); // passes
```

... it also passes if I use a `match` clause.

The error I get using the `?` operator above is:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local data `ids_for_discard`
   --> src\indexing_pool.rs:112:19
    |
112 | ...                   let _ = ids_for_discard.lock()?.push(id_string);
    |                               ----------------------^
    |                               |
    |                               returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
    |                               `ids_for_discard` is borrowed here
```

Can anyone explain why `?` fails to compile here? I'm really struggling to understand. I wondered whether there might be a danger that an attempt is made to `push` an `Err`... but in the event that `lock()` fails, shouldn't this immediately send control, with this `Err`, out of the local closure?

NB this also fails:

```
let id_string = text_doc_hit_obj._id.clone();
let mut vec = ids_for_discard.lock()?;
vec.push(id_string);
```

Compiler: `error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local data 'ids_for_discard'`

Again, if I replace `?` with `unwrap()`, it passes.

I see that the signature of `Mutex::lock()` is
`pub fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuard<'_, T>>`
... and `LockResult` is `pub type LockResult<Guard> = Result<Guard, PoisonError<Guard>>;`. Could it be that `Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` is unable to capture this kind of error???

Comment: Ah... so it means "returns" as in "return an Err"? I understood "returns" to mean what the method `lock` returns... But if that's the case, why is it said to "reference data owned by the current function"? In what way would an `Err` generated by `lock()` be doing that?

Comment: That makes me wonder that `?` ever works in that case. I suppose it must have to do with the close use (in my example) of a "local variable". I'll have to go away and study this. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: For what is worth, it is idiomatic to `unwrap()` the result of a `lock()` instead of propagating it upwards (the exception that proves the rule). `Mutex::lock` only fails if the mutex is poisoned, and if that ever happens panicking is usually the best option.

Comment: Actually nevermind me, the `Err(PoisonError(MutexGuard<'_, T>))` **does** contain a reference to the `Mutex`, so you can't return it from the function. You can use `map_err` to something which doesn't.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks for that. @cafce25 I think I see what your point is there... so the "guard", when it is winkled out of the `Mutex`, is/becomes local... but the possible error wants a reference to it? Nice work out for my limited understanding. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PoisonError` does contain a `MutexGuard` and with it a reference to the `Arc<Mutex<..>>` which in your case is local to the function, so you can't return references to it. You can `map_err` to exchange the error for something which doesn't contain a reference to any local variable:

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;
fn err_on_mutex_poisoned() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let x = Mutex::new(0);
    // x.lock()?; // doesn't work
    x.lock().map_err(|_| "failed")?; // works
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The Rust compiler's messages are more impressive than any other compiler I've ever used, but perhaps one more clue might have been provided in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Mutex::lock returns a [LockResult](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/type.LockResult.html), and according to its documentation:

> Note that the Err variant also carries the associated guard, and it can be acquired through the into_inner method.

I'm not too sure of the circumstances under which it would be advisable to go ahead and use the lock even when it was poisoned, but nevertheless the consequence is that even the error variant contains the lock guard, which references the mutex and thus cannot be returned.

You could map the error into some other kind, eg:

```
let _ = ids_for_discard.lock()
        .map_err(|_| /* some other error here */)?
        .push(id_string);
```

Comment: Looks like both you and cafce25 suggested `map_err` simultaneously. Great minds think alike. Not too sure at this point what a poisoned lock can and can't do, but it doesn't sound great. The main thing I wanted was an explanation, so thanks. In the `Result` API I'd previously seen there are many things you can do to "transform" a `Result`, e.g. `ok`, `or` , `unwrap_or`, etc. But given that the context in this case is child threads, a panic is, as rodrigo says, quite likely to be the most appropriate solution for this.